# Is stripe.js is full alternative to the server code (gem stripe)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Can I use https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js a **full** alternative of the server side code, for example, `gem stripe` in Ruby? I figure I can do something in stripe.js but it will only get me so far. In particular, I can't create and manage Subscriptions, Invoice, InvoiceItems in stripe.js, can I?

Answer (score 2):

[Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) will only permit you a secure but easy way of gathering payment information from your users.

You will still need some server-side or backend code to process the information and finalize the payment, or to manage anything else like subscriptions or invoice items with an API library for the programming language of your choice.